# How can I execute only one Maintenance task in Pimcore? (not all)

Tags: pimcore

I created maintenance job SomeNameDoerTask in Pimcore 10.
But when I try to execute it,

```
bin/console pimcore:maintenance --async
bin/console messenger:consume pimcore_core pimcore_maintenance pimcore_image_optimize --time-limit=300
```

it is that deep in the queue so I can't see it called.

How to execute it explicitely?

Answer (score 1):

Pimcore gives us an ability to run only 1 job:

```
bin/console pimcore:maintenance --force --job=SomeNameDoer --async
```

where the name SomeNameDoer type from tags from Resources/config/maintenance.yml
Was you ever wandering why constructor was called but execute() method was not? Check that you use tag type, not class name.

If you need xDebug it, disable asynchronous run and enable verbosity:

```
bin/console pimcore:maintenance --force --job=SomeNameDoer -vvv
```

To see all available options and MaintenanceTasks:

```
bin/console pimcore:maintenance --help
```

For example,

```
--env=ENV
```

allows you to emulate PROD environment.

Please see that pimcore allows to exclude some job when running all others:

```
bin/console pimcore:maintenance --excludedJobs=SomeNameDoerTask,ImportTask,CleanupTask
```